# CFOBJECT Can't Find Class File

Tags: java, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

One of my ColdFusion 8 templates that uses CFObject can't find a class file that's sitting in the same folder. Anyone have an idea what the trouble is?

**UPDATE:**

- OS: CentOS5
- CF Version: 8

My class file is located here: `/foler1/folder2/folder2/MyClass.class`

When I try and use `<createobject class="MyClass" ...>` from a script in the same directory, I get the error message:

> Object Instantiation Exception. Class not found: MyClass

Comment: Put more relevant information, like error message, log from server, etc.

Comment: .. Also [you cannot just place class files anywhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304479/coldfusion-about-using-custom-own-written-java-classes/12304757#12304757). They must be in the CF class path (see item #3).

Comment: Added to what @JorgeCampos says, posting rather than simply describing the code always helps. THat said, Leigh has answered your question, really.

Comment: *posting rather than simply describing the code always helps* .. And not just by helping us to answer your question. [Including more context/details](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20098299/edit) (hint, hint ;) also helps the next guy searching for an answer to the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your replies.  I solved the problem by placing the folder the class file is in, in the ColdFusion Class path in the CF Administrator under Server Settings > Java and JVM. So, if the class file is MyClass.class is under /foler1/folder2/folder2, I put that folder in that entry. I then restarted CF. This did the trick.