# not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver

Tags: sqlite, jdbc, coldfusion

I have successfully created a ColdFusion datasource to a SQLite database using the [`sqlitejdbc-v056.jar`](http://code.google.com/p/sqlitebot/downloads/detail?name=sqlitejdbc-v056.jar). Then I added this query to my .cfm page

```
<cfquery name="qry" datasource="Spiceworks">
SELECT
id AS Ticket_Number,
summary AS Summary,
status AS Status,
created_at AS Created_At,
assigned_to AS Assigned_to

FROM tickets
WHERE status = 'open' AND assigned_to IS NULL
ORDER BY Created_At DESC   
</cfquery>
```

When I browse to my .cfm page in IE and Firefox, I get the error:

> not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver
>
> The error occurred in C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/intra/SmartTV/UnassignedTickets/Tickets.cfm: line 204
>
> 202 :
>   203 :
>   204 : 
>   205 : SELECT
>   206 : id,
>
> SQL      SELECT id, summary, status, created_at, assigned_to FROM
>   tickets WHERE status = 'open' AND assigned_to IS NULL ORDER BY
>   created_at DESC DATASOURCE      Spiceworks Resources:
>
> ```
> Check the ColdFusion documentation to verify that you are using the correct syntax.
> Search the Knowledge Base to find a solution to your problem.
> ```

Stack Trace

```
at cfTickets2ecfm1617356019.runPage(C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/intra/SmartTV/UnassignedTickets/Tickets.cfm:204) at cfTickets2ecfm1617356019.runPage(C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/intra/SmartTV/UnassignedTickets/Tickets.cfm:204) java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.unused(JDBC3Statement.java:397)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.execute(JDBC3Statement.java:414)
    at coldfusion.server.j2ee.sql.JRunStatement.execute(JRunStatement.java:359)
    at coldfusion.sql.Executive.executeQuery(Executive.java:1442)
    at coldfusion.sql.Executive.executeQuery(Executive.java:1201)
    at coldfusion.sql.Executive.executeQuery(Executive.java:1131)
    at coldfusion.sql.SqlImpl.execute(SqlImpl.java:406)
    at coldfusion.tagext.sql.QueryTag.executeQuery(QueryTag.java:1056)
    at coldfusion.tagext.sql.QueryTag.doEndTag(QueryTag.java:685)
    at cfTickets2ecfm1617356019.runPage(C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\intra\SmartTV\UnassignedTickets\Tickets.cfm:204)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:244)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:444)
    at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65)
    at coldfusion.filter.IpFilter.invoke(IpFilter.java:64)
    at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:428)
    at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
    at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
    at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:112)
    at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94)
    at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
    at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
    at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
    at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:219)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.unused(JDBC3Statement.java:397)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.execute(JDBC3Statement.java:414)
    at coldfusion.server.j2ee.sql.JRunStatement.execute(JRunStatement.java:359)
    at coldfusion.sql.Executive.executeQuery(Executive.java:1442)
    at coldfusion.sql.Executive.executeQuery(Executive.java:1201)
    at coldfusion.sql.Executive.executeQuery(Executive.java:1131)
    at coldfusion.sql.SqlImpl.execute(SqlImpl.java:406)
    at coldfusion.tagext.sql.QueryTag.executeQuery(QueryTag.java:1056)
    at coldfusion.tagext.sql.QueryTag.doEndTag(QueryTag.java:685)
    at cfTickets2ecfm1617356019.runPage(C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\intra\SmartTV\UnassignedTickets\Tickets.cfm:204)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:244)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:444)
    at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65)
    at coldfusion.filter.IpFilter.invoke(IpFilter.java:64)
    at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:428)
    at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
    at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
    at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:112)
    at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94)
    at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
    at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
    at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
    at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:219)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
```

**Update:**

I have my .jar file under `C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\lib\` and `C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\WEB-INF\lib`. In ColdFusion Datasources:

- CF Data Source Name: Spiceworks
- JDBC URL: jdbc:sqlite:\spiceworks\C$\Program Files\Spiceworks\db\spiceworks_prod.db
- Driver Class: org.sqlite.JDBC
- Driver Name: sqlite-jdbc-3.7.15-M1.jar
- User name: `<user>`
- Password: `<password>`

As suggested in the comments, I tried simpler statements:

- `SELECT * FROM tickets`
- `SELECT id, summary, status, assigned_to FROM tickets`

... and [different driver versions](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads)

- sqllite-jdbc4-3.8.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
- sqlite-jdbc-3.7.15-M1.jar

but still got the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55344/discussion-between-leigh-and-wenda).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the original error means exactly what it says. The datasource invoked a method that is not implemented by the driver you are using. Specifically the `execute(..)` method of `org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement`. [The source for this driver](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/src/2ca244ae996247dfd9cbd15fe58553942f2d1e79/src/main/java/org/sqlite/jdbc3/JDBC3Statement.java?at=feature/jdbc4) shows that method does nothing. It simply throws the error message you are seeing.

However I think you have another version of the SQLite driver jar in your class path. The [`sqlitejdbc-v056.jar`](http://code.google.com/p/sqlitebot/downloads/detail?name=sqlitejdbc-v056.jar) you posted could not cause that error because it does not even contain a `JDBC3Statement` class. What is probably happening is that CF is loading another other version of the driver (that is in your class path) instead.

In my tests, the `sqlitejdbc-v056.jar` worked fine with CF10. Before adding that jar again, make sure you have removed *all* versions of the SQLLite jar from your CF class path, and restart CF. Otherwise, CF will still load them automatically and you will continue to get that error message.

To ensure you have removed *all* of the jars, after restarting, try and create an instance of the main class. If the line below throws a "Class not found" error, you know have successfully removed them all. Once you have done that, go ahead an reinstall the `sqlitejdbc-v056.jar`.

```
<cfset obj = createObject("java", "org.sqlite.JDBC")>
If you see this text, you still have a version of the jar in your class path.
```

Here is what worked for me:

1. Created empty database `C:/temp/sqlite/products.db`
2. Downloaded `sqlitejdbc-v056.jar` into `C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\WEB-INF\lib`
3. Restarted CF
4. Created "Other" DSN
5. DSN Settings

   - DS Name: SQLite
   - JDBC URL: jdbc:sqlite:C:/temp/sqlite/products.db
   - Driver Class: org.sqlite.JDBC

Comment: I don't understand what you mean my class path. Please explain further. How do I use the object? Do I not use cfquery? Where did you download the sqlitejdbc-v056.jar at so I know I have the same version.

Comment: The [CF class path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304479/coldfusion-about-using-custom-own-written-java-classes/12304757#12304757), ie the locations CF looks for classes and jars. You will still be using cfquery. The purpose of the `createObject` statement is just to verify you have removed all of the driver jars from your class path. If you have done that correctly, that line should throw an error, because it won't be able to find the class. After that, you do not need it anymore.

Comment: I used [the jar version you posted](http://code.google.com/p/sqlitebot/downloads/detail?name=sqlitejdbc-v056.jar) in the comments.

Comment: I removed the SQLite jar and restarted ColdFusion. The line did throw an error, so I know all driver jars have been removed.Next, I followed your example and I received a different error now."file is encrypted or is not a database" I believe the previous issue "not implemented by SQLITE JDBC Driver" is resolved. I will open a new question for the new error. Thanks Leigh.

Comment: You are welcome. BTW, you can get rid of the `createObject` line now. It was only for testing/debugging. You do not need it any more.