# Unable to execute queries in SQLlite when accessing via H2 console - not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver null/0

Tags: sqlite, h2

I am using the SQLlite as the embedded database in my java web application and i also added the h2 dependency in my project, so that i can access the database through its console. I was able to connect to the database without any issues but unable to run any queries, receiving the error message "java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver", Not receiving any error message when i am performing the same operation in the application.

Answer (score 0):

The program you're using is calling a JDBC method (execute) that the sqlite driver doesn't implement. See the first paragraph [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24130918/9952196) for more discussion.

Short of rewriting the program to use other methods I don't think there's a fix.