# Where to put Java library in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have to put my Java Library in Coldfusion and my Coldfusion's `Java Virtual Machine Path` is **`C:/ColdFusion9/runtime/jre`**

In which location I should consider placing my Java Library ?

1. Coldfusion9/wwwroot/WEB-INF/lib
2. Coldfusion9/runtime/jre/lib

I can see .jar files at both of the above locations. Hence I'm wondering where should I put my downloaded .jar? I will be restarting CF9 after doing this.

More Info: The documentation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23926821/how-do-you-use-java-files-in-coldfusion) says that it should always be in the JVM's classpath as a rule. Could anyone tell me where, or what, is the rule ?

Answer (score 6):

(This does sound like a duplicate, but my remarks are too long for comments)

*Short answer:* 
The simple option is to place the .jar file in `{web_root}/WEB-INF/lib` and restart.

*Longer answer:*
[The thread you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23926821/how-do-you-use-java-files-in-coldfusion) says that .jar files must be placed somewhere within the CF class path. In loose terms, "class path" just means a collection of paths that CF is going to search for jars/classes when the server starts.

Technically - you are free to place a jar file just about anywhere you want. As long as it is accessible to the CF Server and that path is included in the jvm.config file. However, there are certain locations which [CF checks automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304479/coldfusion-about-using-custom-own-written-java-classes/12304757#12304757). So you can just place a jar file in one of those directories and restart. No other changes are needed.

Two of the locations CF checks automatically are:

- `{web_root}/WEB-INF/lib/`
- `{web_root}/WEB-INF/classes/`

The comment about the "rule" refers to a convention for the `/WEB-INF/` folder that specifies `.jar` files should be placed in `WEB-INF/lib/` while *individual* `*.class` files (less common) should be placed in `WEB-INF/classes/`. Since you are using a jar, it would go in `WEB-INF/lib/`.

For more details about how and where CF searches for jars, see also

- [About ColdFusion and Java objects](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec14231-7fe5.html)
- [The Definitive Guide to the ColdFusion Classpath](https://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2004/07/the_definitive.html) (A bit dated, but most of it is still relevant).

Comment: I'd also suggest looking at JavaLoader as it lets you put your jars in the same area as your project.